# Using Alloy functions in a recursive way through transitive closures

Tags: function, recursion, closures, alloy

I am doing a model in Alloy to represent a subset of Java language. Below we have some elements of this model:

```
sig Method {
    id : one MethodId,
    param: lone Type,
    return: one Type,
    acc: lone Accessibility,    
    b: one Block
}

abstract sig Expression {}
abstract sig StatementExpression extends Expression {}

sig MethodInvocation extends StatementExpression{
    pExp: lone PrimaryExpression, 
    id_methodInvoked: one Method,
    param: lone Type
}

sig Block {
    statements: seq StatementExpression
}

pred noRecursiveMethodInvocationCall [] {
    no m:Method | m in ^getMethodInvokedInsideBody[m]
}

fun getMethodInvokedInsideBody [m: Method] : Method {
      (univ.(m.b.statements)).id_methodInvoked
}
```

The problem is that Block has to be a sequence of StatementExpression at the same time that recursive calls to the same method should be avoided. Thus, I thought in the solution above.

When i try to generate the corresponding instances i get the following error type:

```
.
Name cannot be resolved; possible incorrect
function/predicate call; perhaps you used ( ) when you
should have used [ ]

This cannot be a correct call to fun
genericLawsMetaModel/javametamodel_withfield_final/getMethodInvokedInsideBody.
The parameters are
m:
{genericLawsMetaModel/javametamodel_withfield_final/Method}
so the arguments cannot be empty.
```

Still regarding this question, i also tried changing the definition for the predicate noRecursiveMethodInvocationCall (thus eliminating the mentioned function):

```
pred noRecursiveMethodInvocationCall [] {
    no m:Method | m in ^( (univ.(m.b.statements)).id_methodInvoked )
}
```

However, a new type error occurs:

```
^ can be used only with a binary relation.
Instead, its possible type(s) are:
{genericLawsMetaModel/javametamodel_withfield_final/Method}
```

Any clue? I just want to avoid recursive calls to the same method.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

You are misusing the transitive closure operator **^**. 
This latter applies on binary relations solely, not on functions.

I would thus declare MethodInvokedInsideBody as a field of the Method and use transitive closure on it the way you did.

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of how the transitive closure operator can be used in order to achieve what you want to achieve:

```
sig Method {
    id : one MethodId,
    param: lone Type,
    return: one Type,
    acc: lone Accessibility,    
    b: one Block
    methodsInvokedInsideBody: set Method
}

pred noRecursiveMethodInvocationCall{
    no m:Method | m in m.^methodsInvokedInsideBody
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
Loïc Gammaitoni, thank you for your response. But, can you be more clear? (see my question edition, i tried to do what i suppose you suggested but it does not work =/ )

Comment: I edited my answer. In your second attempt you try to apply the transitive closure operator on a singleton of type Method. This is not a binary relation, as the error message highlights, hence the error.